# MSDeploy publish via FTP

Tags: iis, deployment, msdeploy

I'd like to use MSDeploy, mainly for packaging and its support for syncing. I'm using MSBuild, along with TeamCity, to automate publishing when I merge to the master branch in git.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the destination has the IIS (nor the will to install) services. So, my best option is FTP. Does MSDeploy support FTP as a publishing method? Or am I stuck using the _CopyWebApplication target and the FtpUploadDirectoryContent MSBuild Community Task?

Thanks
Bryce Fischer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's strictly HTTP(S).